# whenever i am writing some text in brackets between the HTML tags, the text gets overwritten on tags which then causes the charactes of tags to erase

Tags: command-line

whenever i am writing a text between any HTML tags, the text is getting overwritten on the tags which then causes the tags to get delete.Usually the tags would move aside when i write between them but it is not happening now.My code editor is Bracket.For example when i  write hi between title tags, this happens

```html
<title>hi</title>   {normally  
<title>hitile>      {now this happens
```

the letters on the text is getting overwritten on the arrow(<)and slash(/).

Another example when i write a text like hello

```html
<title>hello</title>    {normally  
<title>hellole>          {now this happens
```

the text text hello is getting overwritten on the arrow, slash,t,i and the letter t which is then causing the characters of the tag to get erase.

Please someone HELP me!

Comment: You've provided no OS/release details; nor what software you're actually talking about. Where I see what you're describing is mostly on *wordpress*, but as you've provided few details as to what app & how it was installed (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=bracket doesn't reveal much; so please be specific with details)

Comment: This seems like a rather classic case of the "Insert" key being toggled to overwrite mode instead of insert mode.

Answer (score 2):

The default behavior for most text editors is that the <kbd>Insert</kbd> key toggles between "Insert" mode and "Overwrite" mode. It seems that your application right now is in "Overwrite" mode.

Press the <kbd>Insert</kbd> by default to toggle back to "Insert" mode. Some applications may have special shortcuts to achieve this, but <kbd>Insert</kbd> is the default.